# Add elements and objects to array

Tags: javascript

here’s what I’m trying to do:

```
state={
  show:true,
  key:'',
  sections: [{title:'primary',data:['a','b']},{title:'test',data:[1,2]}]
}
```

I need to add elements to the data arrays and I need to add Objects to the sections array

Comment: 1) fix formatting 2) this is just a simple property access?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
var state={
 show:true,
 key:'',
 sections: [{title:'primary',data:['a','b']},{title:'test',data:[1,2]}]
}

state.sections.push({title:'new',data:['e','f']});
console.log(state.sections);
```

Comment: That’s great for adding objects. Do I just use state.sections.data.push to add elements to the data array?

Comment: @DCR sections is an array of object, so to add elements in data of any object in section you need to do : state.sections[index].data.push(element)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `push()` function to add item into an array:

```js
let state={
    show:true,
    key:'',
    sections: [{title:'primary',data:['a','b']},{title:'test',data:[1,2]}]
}

state.sections[0].data.push('c');

state.sections.push({title:'title',data:['2','5']});
console.log(state.sections);

//for react setState
this.setState({
  state.sections: [...this.state.sections, {title:'title',data:['2','5']}]
})
```

Comment: We need to use setState to change state

Comment: @DCR are you want to use react setState?

Answer (score 1):

Pushing a new section is easy:

```
state.sections.push({title:'someTitle',data:[2, 3]});
```

To push new data, you need to specify *which* data you want to push to. For example to push into the `test` section, you must first get a reference to the `test` object, then push:

```js
var state= {
  show:true,
  key:'',
  sections: [{title:'primary',data:['a','b']},{title:'test',data:[1,2]}]
 }

let section = state.sections.find(item => item.title == 'test')
section.data.push(3)

console.log(state)
```

This assumes the titles are unique because `find()` only finds the first matching item. You might also want to test that `find()` actually found something if there's a chance you'll search for titles that don't exist.